# Service Fabric UpgradeOrchestrationService fails

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am currently testing Service Fabric on a standalone Windows Server 2016 Datacenter installation.

The cluster consists of three nodes, which are running on a single machine (similar configuration to *ClusterConfig.Unsecure.DevCluster.json*). The cluster version is 5.3.301.9590. Setting up the cluster worked without any issues. However after some delay, the **UpgradeOrchestrationService** in the system section of Service Fabric Explorer enters into warning state. An application is not installed. The situation occurs directly after cluster setup.

The following exception message is displayed:

```
  Unhealthy event: SourceId='RunAsync', Property='RunAsyncUnhandledException', HealthState='Warning', ConsiderWarningAsError=false.
  System.Fabric.FabricException (-2147017720) 
   Message: Exception from HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFFF 
   StackTrace:    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Fabric.Common.FabricClientRetryHelper.d__15.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Fabric.Common.FabricClientRetryHelper.d__f.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Fabric.UpgradeService.ClusterUpgradeCommandProcessor.d__46.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Fabric.UpgradeService.ClusterUpgradeCommandProcessor.d__34.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Fabric.UpgradeOrchestration.Service.FabricUpgradeOrchestrationService.d__15.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Fabric.UpgradeOrchestration.Service.FabricUpgradeOrchestrationService.d__a.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Fabric.UpgradeOrchestration.Service.FabricUpgradeOrchestrationService.d__2.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatefulServiceReplicaAdapter.d__f.MoveNext()
```

## Update

I did the exact same setup on Windows Server 2012 R2 and did not encounter any issues.

Comment: Can you check for messages in the Event Viewer under Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft-Service Fabric? Sounds like something related to the cluster configuration.